# SAP get Sales Orders BAPISDORDER_GETDETAILEDLIST

Tags: c#, sap-erp, saprfc, bapi

I'm trying to call `BAPISDORDER_GETDETAILEDLIST` to get the sales orders form SAP into my C# application, but for some reason `headerTable` doesn't return any information.

Any clues?

This is how I do it:

```
public DataTable getVariantConfiguratioin(String ordernumber)
        {
            IRfcFunction testfn = repo.CreateFunction("BAPISDORDER_GETDETAILEDLIST");


            IRfcStructure data = testfn.GetStructure("I_BAPI_VIEW");
            IRfcTable salesDocuments = testfn.GetTable("SALES_DOCUMENTS");
            IRfcTable headerTable = testfn.GetTable("ORDER_HEADERS_OUT");
           
            data.SetValue("HEADER", "X");
            data.SetValue("ITEM", "X");
            data.SetValue("SDCOND", "X");

            
            salesDocuments.Append();
            salesDocuments.SetValue("VBELN", ordernumber);

            testfn.Invoke(dest);


            DataTable headerTableDT = headerTable.ToDataTable("headerTableDT");

            return headerTableDT;

        }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

make sure youa have left 0 padded your order number exemple to the correct length of VBELN in your system . example:

```
salesDocuments.setValue("VBELN", "0000001258")
```

please also check after invoke headerTable.RowCount

Witch version of sap connector youre using ... i dont have IRfcTable.toDataTable in 3.0 ?

Comment: oh god, thanks man. i forgott the 0.
i use sap connector 3.0. the "todatatable" is a additional function i added